# XBOX ONE controller has a loose port

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one

Is there a way to fix this? My cord keeps falling out. I use it to play on PC, and certain games MUST have the controller plugged in BEFORE you start them in order to recognize the device. This means whenever I DO have this problem, I end up restarting the whole game.

Duct tape is an option, but it's ugly, and I want to know if there's another way first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess you have one of the early models of the controller if not the Day One Edition like I did. I had this exact same problem and early on in the life cycle of Xbox One they came out fairly quickly with some controller iterations that improved upon things like this. If your controller doesn't have the headphone jack in the bottom of it then it is an older model and I HIGHLY recommend upgrading to one of the newer ones. Trading in a controller and a couple games may help bring the price down on a new controller if that is an issue.

Comment: Well, it's not an early model, it's the [PDP Legendary Edition](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA0PG5492665&cm_re=deliverer_of_truth-_-9SIA0PG5492665-_-Product). The only thing I use it for is PC games, I don't actually have an XB1. I don't want to get rid of it, the buttons are really great. So... duct tape it is.